# Jekyll: Mp4/WebM video showing on serve, but not on build?

Tags: html, video, jekyll

I would like a short video on the [index page of my site](https://tmorville.github.io/). I have the [video](https://gfycat.com/CleanEarlyGrayreefshark) as .mp4 and .webm format in my /images/ folder. This works perfectly when serving with `bundle exec jekyll serve`, however my site won't actually show the video.

This is the simple code in index.html that embeds it

```
---
layout: default
---

<video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"a width="768" height="512">
  <source src="/images/lorenz.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="/images/lorenz.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Videos on your site are located under `/assets/images`, while you are referring them in the homepage at `/images/`. Change the location of the videos and they will load properly:

```
---
layout: default
---

<video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" width="768" height="512">
  <source src="/assets/images/lorenz.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="/assets/images/lorenz.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Comment: Wow. That was incredibly slow of me. Thanks.